# Creating datasets within Macro SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
%macro MSA (Data=, Code=, MSAName=);
    data &Data;
    set NoDup;
        %if MSA = &Code %then %do; 
        MSA_name = "&MSAName";
        output &data;
   %end; 
   run; 
   %mend MSA;
   %MSA (Data=Bakersfield, Code=12540, MSAName=Bakersfield);
   %MSA (Data=Chico,       Code=17020, MSAName=Chico);
```

So I get two datasets as I want with one names Bakersfield and another Chico. However, the MSA column does not display the correct value (i.e. a column of 12540 for Bakersfield and 17020 for Chico for MSA), nor do I get a variable named MSA_Name that gives me the correct values (Bakersfield for all of the MSA_Name column, and Chico). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be clear on what is happening: The macro statements simply generate the SAS statements that will be executed. `MSA = 12540;` is false (the macro processor doesn't access the variables in your data set, it just compares text), so the following code is executed: `data Bakersfield; set NoDup; run;`. You are just copying your data set.

Comment: You are exactly right. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The issues you have with your code is to mingle macro syntax with data step. Please try the following:

```
%macro MSA (Data=, Code=, MSAName=);
    data &Data;
    set NoDup;
        if MSA = &Code /*if MSA is char, you will need quote "&code"*/ then  do;
        MSA_name = "&MSAName"; output; end;
      run; 
   %mend MSA;
   %MSA (Data=Bakersfield, Code=12540, MSAName=Bakersfield);
   %MSA (Data=Chico,       Code=17020, MSAName=Chico);
```

Comment: The result from this code wasn't any different from mine.

Comment: There is no %-sign in this solutions IF, THEN etc. Original code use %IF and it doesn't work when MSA is an observation not a macro variable. Sure there isn't any difference?

Comment: @user2916331 He took out your output statement. Use a `do` block like this instead: `if MSA = "&Code" then do; MSA_name = "&MSAName"; output; end;`.

Comment: @DWal, why you need an explicit 'output' when an implicit 'output' is in place and does the exact same thing?

Comment: Explicit OUTPUT is needed to make the output dataset a subset of the input data set.  Otherwise the program is just copy the data and generating MSA_NAME for only some of the records.

Comment: @HaikuoBian I put `output` in the `do` block so it executes only when `MSA = "&code"` is true. It seems based on the initial code that OP wants to make subsets of the input data set rather than outputting every line.

Comment: @DWal, Tom: Both of you are correct! I am editing my answer to reflect this change.